# Export from localhost to remote on the same LAN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to export one of my database to my Raspberry. I tried through PHPMyadmin, but on import I got this errormessage:

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `leltar`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `eventlog`
--

CREATE TABLE `eventlog` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `productbc` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_hungarian_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_hungarian_ci' at line 16
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Please post your target MySQL version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your datetime field has [fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html) specified: `datetime(1)`.

This feature is probably not supported by the target mysql version (< v5.7), hence the error message.

You either need to upgrade your target mysql version to support fractional seconds or you need to remove the fractional seconds from the export file, both from the data definition and the data itself.

Comment: The data might not need to be changed. MySQL will probably truncate or round it.

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem. I only wanted to "clone" the structure, so data wasn't imported/exported.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `eventlog` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `productbc` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "(1)" after the word "datetime" because it <strike>needs no length</strike> (sorry, it's not "length" it is a fractional seconds specification). The following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE `eventlog` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `productbc` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_hungarian_ci;
```

Comment: It is not length, it is fractional seconds as I pointed out in my answer.